# How to browse local hard disk through file manager in Debox live cd?

Tags: livecd

I just made a Debox live CD to transfer files from my hard drive to a USB stick. I can access the USB storage in the media folder, but I'm unable to find the local hard drive. How can I access it?

Comment: It looks like you tried to communicate by posting an "answer" from another account. Please read [*I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?*](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) The question owner can post comments or edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Download "Ultimate Boot CD" and install on usb or disc. 
From there boot into from start of Device, run "Partition Magic". 
From there can transfer files from disc to disc.

Answer (score 0):

most likely deboxOS in the format of the liveCD does not support the NTFS of your Windows 7. Try installing the package ntfs-3g (if you have the Internet in Debox OS) and to mount the necessary partitions. If you are logged in as a user, open the terminal and run the command

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

on the password request, answer root (the password will not be visible)

Identifying partition with NTFS file system

```
fdisk -l | grep ntfs
```

Determine which partition you need (sda1, sda2, or sdbX) and mount it

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs 

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs
```

Now we can access NTFS partition and its files with read write access.

more info: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

https://beginlinux.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/mounting-an-ntfs-drive-in-debian/